# webusb - DOMException: Access denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, webusb

```
document.getElementById('usb').addEventListener('click',async function(){
    var device;

    navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{name:'usb', vendorId: 0x76C }] })
        .then(selectedDevice => {
            device = selectedDevice;
            return device.open(); 
  })
        .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1)) 
        .then(() => device.claimInterface(2)) 
        .then(() => device.controlTransferOut({
            requestType: 'class',
            recipient: 'interface',
            request: 0x22,
            value: 0x01,
            index: 0x02})) // Ready to receive data
        .then(() => device.transferIn(5, 64)) 
        .then(result => {
            let decoder = new TextDecoder();
            console.log('Received: ' + decoder.decode(result.data));
        })
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); });
})
```

usbweb show this error, tried some solution but can't find, any one help this problem. this error DOMException: Access denied.

Comment: are you accessing this page over HTTPS?

Comment: No bro. localhost

Comment: HTTPS also same problem

Comment: Please add information about the device you are trying to connect to and what operating system you are on. If, for example, you are on Windows and trying to connect to a device implementing the USB CDC protocol you will get the "Access Denied" error because Windows does not allow you to open a device which is claimed by a more specific driver. You will need to use the Zadig tool to replace the driver with the generic WinUSB.sys driver.